# thread safe queueable counter in c#

Tags: c#, queue, thread-safety

I am looking for a thread-safe queue-able counter similar to `Interlocked.Increment(ref counter)`. By queue-able, I mean being able to take the next number in sequence, but then return it back to the top of the queue when I'm done with it. Is something similar to this already build into C#?

Example: I take (0,1,2,3,4,5) in order. Then I return 4. Then I return 1. So the next number in the queue would be (1,4,6,7,etc.)

EDIT:

Thanks all for the help. I believe the following will work for my needs:

```
    ConcurrentStack<int> _stack = new ConcurrentStack<int>();
    private int _max;

    public EntityStack()
    {
        _stack.Push(0);
        _max = 0;
    }

    public int GetNextHandle()
    {
        int handle;
        var success = _stack.TryPop(out handle);

        if (_stack.Count == 0)
        {
            _max += 1;
            _stack.Push(_max);
        }

        return handle;
    }

    public void ReturnHandle(int handle)
    {
        _stack.Push(handle);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to write the code yourself?

Comment: I don't understand your example.

Comment: I have found ConcurrentQueue; is that the best option for a thread-safe queue? I have searched but haven't found a better option yet...

Comment: @tval Seems like you want an ordered queue, and the "next number" for when it's empty.

Comment: What you are describing looks more like a stack than a queue.

Comment: @JuanR I think your are absolutely right. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @tval But what if you return 1 then return 4.  Should the next one be 4, because that's what a stack would do.  If it should always be 1 no matter the order they are returned then you need a sorted collection,

Comment: @juharr I see your point as well. Perhaps a priority queue then?

Comment: Do you need the numbers available in the collection to be popped or dequeued in order?

Comment: I was just considering that. The answer is no. I just need to be able to re-use the number. Order is not important. Which, by that means, validates the acceptance of using a stack.

Comment: If order is irrelevant then you don't even need a stack.  You just need literally any collection that you can add and remove items from, whether it be a stack, queue, bag, or whatever.  The type of collection only matters if you care about what item you get back when you ask for an item.

Comment: @Servy makes a valid point. If you don't care about the number, then you just need any collection that can accept and give one. Any class that implements `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the number returned, then you just need any collection that can accept and give one. Any class that implements the `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` interface will do:

- `BlockingCollection<T>`
- `ConcurrentQueue<T>`
- `ConcurrentStack<T>`

Comment: You shouldn't be doing a busywait to get/add items.  If you want to do a blocking wait while you wait for items, then use a `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: @Servy: I updated my answer based on comments from the OP.

Comment: If you care about duplicates then you *still* need to make sure that you don't add them when using a `ConcurrentQueue` or a `ConcurrentStack`, as neither of those are going to verify uniqueness of the items in them.  Since the OP needs unique items it's something they're going to need to ensure as a user of the collection, not something they can expect the collection to enforce for them.

Comment: @Servy: True. I updated the answer. Mulitasking has its effects... :-)